# APS Scheduler raising exception for no reason django

Tags: django, cron, scheduled-tasks

Even though the target function is receiving both the arguments it's still throwing an error for missing parameters ? wonder why

```
check_device() missing 1 required positional argument: 'device_id'
    Job "check_device (trigger: interval[0:00:30], next run at: 2021-11-05 19:35:24 IST)" raised an exception
```

***Scheduler snip***

```
def job_add(application_id,device_id,count):
    scheduler.add_job(
        check_device,
        'interval',
        args = (application_id,device_id,),
        seconds=7,
        jobstore = 'default',
        id=f'my_job_{count}',
        replace_existing=True,
        max_instances = 7,
        misfire_grace_time=None
    )
```

*function i am calling*

```
def check_device(application_id,device_id):
    print('Mqtt connected ... calling on ',application_id,device_id)
    mqttc = mqtt.Client(clientId)
```

Comment: can you show the check_device function definition?

Comment: @KZiovas code is updated

Comment: did you try  args = [application_id,device_id,],  ?

Comment: i run your code and ti works, maybe you are not passing in the argument correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dummy version of your code which works. Make sure you pass the arguments and call the functions correctly :

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler


def check_device(application_id, device_id):
    print(f"Application id: {application_id}, Device id: {device_id}")


scheduler = BlockingScheduler()


def job_add(application_id, device_id, count):
    scheduler.add_job(
        check_device,
        "interval",
        args=(
            application_id,
            device_id,
        ),
        seconds=2,
        jobstore="default",
        id=f"my_job_{count}",
        replace_existing=True,
        max_instances=7,
        misfire_grace_time=None,
    )


job_add(application_id=5, device_id=2, count=1)
scheduler.start()
```

Comment: thanks for the time, put seemed parameters where not the problem

Answer (score 0):

Okay so posting this answer for future reference , I believe APS stores every job (function) signature in someway in the database I previously added a job with one parameter, after making changes it was searching for the previously defined function as well, but it had no positional parameter for *device_id* , Solution , just delete previous job history from DB ( *this answer may not be precise but if it seems to be giving the above mention error for no reason, deleting related job history should do the job*)

Comment: what database? That does not seem to be correct I just created a function with the same name as you said initially with one parameter and then with two. It didn't raise any errors. Are you sure you have saved your code before running it? Maybe you updated the function but did not save the code. Or maybe you did not re-run the job_add() function after changing your check_device() so the scheduler had the original function saved.These are the only possible solutions.

Comment: yes, it maintains jobs in DB as we know, and using job_id if its distinct it keeps track for that at the job, but now say , you decide to pass the parameter to the job it will give you the error, anyway, I could generate the error again but that's not the point, removing the data for old job helped,

Comment: @KZiovas your answer is off-course correct ideally and syntactically

Comment: Hello. But what DB are you reffering to? apscheduler does not work with a database, not without you configuring it to. Apscheduler stores jobs in memory. You can make a persistent job store but that is not a given at all. If you had a persistent job store then yes that would cause the behavior you describe. But if so please mention it in the question so people are not confused.

Comment: @KZiovas I am talking about Django dbstore and I believe they're in some persistent ?

Comment: ok I see maybe that is a specific Django behavior, I am not familiar with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238927/discussion-between-atif-shafi-and-kziovas).